# What Does This Instruction Do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to Python and I don't understand an instruction in the following program:

```
n = int(input("enter an number : ")
b = 3
p = 1
while n > 0:
   n,r = n//2,n%2
   p* = b**r
   b = b*b
print(p)
```

I don't understand this statement: `n,r = n//2,n%2`. What does it do?

Comment: `a, b = c, d` is in Python the same as `a=c` and `b=d`.

Comment: @Piinthesky It's the same if you think in terms of `a=c` and `b=d` being executed in parallel, so both `c` and `d` are evaluated before either assignment is done. It's not the same if you think of those two assignments being executed one after the other. In OP's code, you could not translate `n, r = n//2, n%2` into `n = n//2; r = n%2`.

Comment: @MichaelGeary Excellent point as demonstrated by `a, b = a - b, a + b`

Comment: It's worth noting that the right side of the assignment you're asking about is the equivalent of the `divmod` builtin function. `n, r = divmod(n, 2)` might be easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the answers are incorrect.

`a, b = c, d` is a Pythonic concept called "tuple unpacking".

`n,r=n//2,n%2` does mean "assign `n//2` to `n`" and "assign `n % 2` to `r`" but `n,r` is a `tuple`. In tuple unpacking, all expressions on the RHS are evaluated **before** assignments. Thus `n` is **not** mutated by `n//2` before `n%2` is evaluated.

Proof of concept for order of operations in tuple unpacking:

```
a = 1
b = 2

a, b = b, a

if (a==2 and b==1):
  print("look ma, I can swap values without needing a temporary variable!")
```

Comment: Thanks for some sanity!

Answer (score 3):

It's a parallel assignment:

```
n, r = n // 2, n % 2
```

`n` equals `n` divided by `2` using integer division, and `r` equals `n` modulo `2`. It's the same as:

```
t1 = n // 2
t2 = n % 2
n  = t1
r  = t2
```

The values to the right are evaluated, and after that they're assigned, to defer overwriting the original values until we no longer need them.

Comment: I think it is confusing to say that the order matters. It seems to imply to me that you fully evaluate and assign the tuple values from right to left when actually you evaluate everything on the right hand side before doing any assignment. The fact that it works assigning from right to left in this case is just an accident, in other cases you'd have to pick some other order.

Comment: @Turn is right. Python is not going to analyze your code to see which order it needs to do the assignments in to avoid any conflict. Depending on the expressions involved, that may not even be possible. It simply evaluates all of the right hand sides first, and then does all the assignments.

Comment: @Turn ok, I redacted better what I meant to say Can we take the downvote now, please? there was no need for it, a simple comment and I would have done it anyway.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez Thanks for editing your answer and sure, I'll undo my downvote now. But I disagree there was no need for it. You posted a clearly technically incorrect answer, that's what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 3):

It is tuple assignment. The each value in the tuple on the left is assigned to the respective value in the tuple on the right. Since the values on the right side are evaluated before any assignment occurs, the value of `n` before the statement is used. So the line is equivalent to:

```py
tmp = n
n = tmp // 2
r = tmp % 2
```